# Bottom Half of Screen is Glitchy

Tags: display, gpu-driver

Total newbie here...

I'm running 12.04 on a salvaged HP Pavilion zt1130. Video is S3 Savage4 AGP 4x... No idea if it's a card or what. I'm unable to find *anything* about a driver.

I'm having a half-screen problem similar to the issues with gma500... Bottom half of the gui is buggy and I can't move the pointer into that area, nor is the pointer visible in the upper half.

Suggestions? I've tried the solutions mentioned [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsVideoCardsPoulsbo#Live_.28Desktop.29_CD) in hopes that it might be a similar issue, but no luck.

Comment: You should at least add the output of `lspci` to the question.